# CompletableFuture: proper way to run a list of futures, wait for result and handle exception

Tags: java, asynchronous, design-patterns, java-8, completable-future

I have a legacy code which have dozen database calls to populate a report, it takes noticeable amount of time which I try to reduce using `CompletableFuture`.

I have some doubts that I do things correctly and not overuse this technology.

My code now looks like this:

1. Start asynchronous population of document sections with many database calls inside each methods

   ```
   CompletableFuture section1Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> populateSection1(arguments));
   CompletableFuture section2Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> populateSection2(arguments));
       ...
   CompletableFuture section1oFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> populateSection10(arguments));
   ```
2. Then I'm arranging futures in specific order in `arrayList` and joining all of them to make sure that my code will run further only when all futures are finished.

   ```
   List<CompletableFuture> futures = Arrays.asList(
               section1Future,
               section2Future, ...
               section10Future);

   List<Object> futureResults = futures.stream()
               .map(CompletableFuture::join)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
3. Then I'm populating PDF document itself with its pieces

   ```
   Optional.ofNullable((PdfPTable) futureResults.get(0)).ifPresent(el -> populatePdfElement(document, el));
   Optional.ofNullable((PdfPTable) futureResults.get(1)).ifPresent(el -> populatePdfElement(document, el));
       ...
   Optional.ofNullable((PdfPTable) futureResults.get(10)).ifPresent(el -> populatePdfElement(document, el));
   ```

   return document

My concerns are:

1) Is it okay to create and instantiate many Completable Futures in such way? Order them in required sequence in `arrayList`, join them to make sure that they are all finished, and then get result by casting them into specific object?

2) Is it okay to run without specifying an executor service but to rely on common `ForkJoinPool`? However this code runs in web container, so probably in order to use JTA I need to use container provided thread pool executor via JNDI?

3) If this code is surrounded in try-catch I should be able to catch `CompletionException` in main thread, right? Or In order to do that I should declare each features like following:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> populateSection1(arguments))
    .exceptionally (ex -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex.getCause());
        });
```

4) Is it possible to overuse CompletableFutures so they become a  performance bottleneck  itself? Like many futures waits one executor to start running? How to avoid that? Use container provided executor service?
If yes, could someone please point me to some best practice on how to correctly configure executor service taking to account processors and memory amount?

5) A memory impact. I read in parallel thread that there can be a problem with OOME as many object are created and garbage collected. Is there a best practice on how to calculate correct amount of memory required for application?

Comment: what you really want is to parallelize your program in hope it will run faster. So first you need to depict a schema of your parallelized program, and only then choose the most appropriate tools to implement it. Besides CompletableFuture, there exist threads, parallel and reactive streams, and actors, to name a few. Are you sure CompletableFuture is the best tool for your task?

Comment: Thanks for reply Alexei! Yes I try to parallelize in order to speed up an already written Spring monolith. I'm using CompletableFuture because I didn't have a chance to work with other asynchronous stuff except Play! framework which AFAIK is backed by CF.  But if to abstract from application is it okay to instantiate, run, join and get result of CompletableFuture in this way? Am I wrong saying that CompletableFuture is aimed to ease developer life using it instead of threads? P.S I'm not saying that I'm not interested or scary to learn best practices of pure multithreading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach is not wrong in general, but there are things to improve.

Most notably, you should not use *raw types*, like `CompletableFuture`.

When `populateSection…` returns a `PdfPTable`, you should use use `CompletableFuture<PdfPTable>` consistently throughout the code.

I.e.

```
CompletableFuture<PdfPTable> section1Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()  -> populateSection1(arguments));
CompletableFuture<PdfPTable> section2Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()  -> populateSection2(arguments));
    ...
CompletableFuture<PdfPTable> section10Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> populateSection10(arguments));
```

even if these methods do not declare the return type you are assuming to be always returned at runtime, you should insert the type cast at this early stage:

```
CompletableFuture<PdfPTable> section1Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()  -> (PdfPTable)populateSection1(arguments));
CompletableFuture<PdfPTable> section2Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()  -> (PdfPTable)populateSection2(arguments));
    ...
CompletableFuture<PdfPTable> section10Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> (PdfPTable)populateSection10(arguments));
```

Then, you can use

```
Stream.of(section1Future, section2Future, ..., section10Future)
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEachOrdered(el -> populatePdfElement(document, el));
```

By not using raw types, you already get the desired result type and you can do the 3rd step’s operations, i.e. filtering and performing the final action, right in this stream operation.

If you still need the list, you may use

```
List<PdfPTable> results = Stream.of(section1Future, section2Future, ..., section10Future)
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

results.forEach(el -> populatePdfElement(document, el));
```

---

That said, the parallelism depends on the thread pool used for the operation (specified to `supplyAsync`). When you don’t specify an executor, you get the default Fork/Join pool used by parallel streams, so in this specific case, you get the same result much simpler as

```
List<PdfPTable> results = Stream.<Supplier<PdfPTable>>.of(
    ()  -> populateSection1(arguments),
    ()  -> populateSection2(arguments));
    ...
    () -> populateSection10(arguments)))
    .parallel()
    .map(Supplier::get)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEachOrdered(el -> populatePdfElement(document, el));
```

or

```
List<PdfPTable> results = Stream.<Supplier<PdfPTable>>.of(
    ()  -> populateSection1(arguments),
    ()  -> populateSection2(arguments));
    ...
    () -> populateSection10(arguments)))
    .parallel()
    .map(Supplier::get)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

results.forEach(el -> populatePdfElement(document, el));
```

While both variants ensure that `populatePdfElement` will be called in the right order and one at a time, only the latter will perform all calls from the initiating thread.

Regarding exception handling, you’ll get any exception thrown by a supplier wrapped in a `CompletionException` when you call `CompletableFuture::join`. Chaining something like `.exceptionally (ex -> { throw new RuntimeException(ex.getCause()); });` makes no sense, the new `RuntimeException` will also be wrapped in a `CompletionException` when you call `CompletableFuture::join`.

In the Stream variant, you’ll get the exception without a wrapper. Since `Supplier` does not allow checked exceptions, only subtypes of `RuntimeException` or `Error` are possible.

The other questions are too broad for the Q&A.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Holger. I like your approach of using forEachOrdered. The one thing I should probably have mentioned is that there is one section which I'm still refactoring (as for now it requires repopulated document) and this section should be inserted in between others in predefined order( Thus I cannot apply this approach  in my code  for now. Regarding shared ForkJoin pool - AFAIK threads are not supposed to be created within an application but has to be used a container provided executer service which also have an access to  transaction manager?

Comment: If you are required to use a specific executor service, you have to pass it to the `supplyAsync` method. Then, you can still use the solution of the first part of the answer.